# Duplicate certain expression by using regex in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

Let's say I have the following line:

```
def __init__(a,b,c):
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
def __init__(a,b,c):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
```

Is there some way I could do this in emacs? I usually do this kind of things manually, but i was wondering if there is some short and handy way to do this :)

My first step would be to copy "a,b,c" and replace "," by newlines, but then I'm stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fully automated way to do this is with `auto-yasnippet` extension.
You can get it from MELPA.

Here are the steps:

1. Type `self.~a = ~a`.
   Here `~` is the prefix which points to what you want replaced.
2. Call `aya-create`.
   I bind it to <kbd>H-w</kbd>, because it's similar in spirit to <kbd>M-w</kbd>.
   The command works on current line if the region isn't active, otherwise on the region.
   After this you get `self.a = a` as your source, and a yasnippet
   template saved similar to the way you save text to the kill ring.
3. Now move to the new line and call `aya-open-line`.
   I bind it to <kbd>H-y</kbd>, because it's similar to <kbd>C-y</kbd>.
   You fill in the field `b` and call `aya-open-line` again to exit the snippet.
   This command moves to the next mirror if there are multiple in a snippet.
4. Repeat again with `c` and you're done.

Here's a slightly shorter way to do it, it works only for single line snippets.
Enter `self.$ =` and call `aya-create`. Then enter `a` and `aya-open-line` to exit.
As you can see, `$` inserts a mirror and another one is added at point.

You can find more examples of usage at https://github.com/abo-abo/auto-yasnippet.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet that does what you want, I think, verbatim:

```elisp
(defun init-expand ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (re-search-backward "(\\([^)]+\\))" nil t))
  (let ((params (split-string (buffer-substring (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)) ",")))
    (loop for param in params
       do (progn
            (newline-and-indent)
            (insert (format "self.%s = %s" param param))))))
```

Evaluating that method (C-M-x when the cursor is within or right after the closing parentheses) then switching to your python buffer (it's python, right?) and moving the cursor right after the ending `:`, and finally calling that function with `M-x init-expand` will set those parameters to self.

Although it's very specific to your question and, as such, is not very portable, it might help you figure out how to use some elisp functions to help you with other helpers you can think of.  That said, I haven't looked into [YASnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) which looks like, from abo-abo's answer, that it provides the tools to accomplish this better.

Comment: I think abo-abo's answer fits better, because its more general. But I will definitely use this to learn a bit more about elisp functions! (And yes, this is from a Python script ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Enable a new version of [YASnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) and have the following snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: init
# key: init
# --
def __init__ ($1):
    ${1:$(mapconcat (function (lambda (x) (if (string= x "") "" (concat "    self." x " = " x)))) (split-string yas-text ",") "\n")}
    $0
```

No ending new line though.